# Color map based on countries' frequency counts

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I have users data set with Country column, and want to plot a map of users' distribution across the countries. I converted the data set into a dictionary, where keys are Country names, and values - frequency counts for countries. The dictionary looks like this:

```
'usa': 139421,
'canada': 21601, 
'united kingdom': 18314,
'germany': 17024,
'spain': 13096,
 [...]
```

To plot distribution on a world map I used this code:

```
#Convert to dictionary
counts = users['Country'].value_counts().to_dict()

#Country names
def getList(dict): 
    return [*dict]

countrs = getList(counts)

#Frequency counts
freqs = list(counts.values())

#Plotting
data = dict(
        type = 'choropleth',
        colorscale = 'Viridis',
        reversescale = True,
        locations = countrs,
        locationmode = "country names",
        z = freqs,
        text = users['Country'],
        colorbar = {'title' : 'Number of Users'},
      ) 

layout = dict(title = 'Number of Users per Country',
                geo = dict(showframe = False)
             )

choromap = go.Figure(data = [data],layout = layout)
iplot(choromap,validate=False)
```

This is the result I got:
[image]

The coloring is wrong; it shows that all countries fall into 0-20K range, which is false. Is there a way to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without access to your complete dataset, this is really hard to answer. I'd suggest starting out with this example instead:

**Plot 1:**

[image]

Here you can simply replace `lifeExp` with your data and everything should be fine as long as your data has a correct format. In the following snippet I've created random integeres for each country to represent your `counts` variable.

**Code:**

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12)
gapminder = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")
gapminder['counts'] = np.random.uniform(low=100000, high=200000, size=len(gapminder)).tolist()

fig = px.choropleth(gapminder, locations="iso_alpha",
                    color="counts", 
                    hover_name="country", # column to add to hover information
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)

fig.show()
```

**Plot 2:**

[image]

Let me know how this works out for you.

**Edit: suggestion with your data:**

If you have a dictionary with country names and counts, you can easily construct a dataframe of it and perform a left join to get this:

**Plot 2:**

[image]

Just make sure that your ***dictionary values are lists***, and that the country names are spelled and formatted correctly.

**Code 2:**

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(12)
gapminder = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")
#gapminder['counts'] = np.nan

d = {'United States': [139421],
    'Canada': [21601], 
    'United Kingdom': [18314],
    'Germany': [17024],
    'Spain': [13096]}

yourdata = pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index()
yourdata.columns=['country', 'count']

df=pd.merge(gapminder, yourdata, how='left', on='country')

fig = px.choropleth(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                    color="count", 
                    hover_name="country", # column to add to hover information
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)

fig.show()
```